# What should a method return if it is not an option I want?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this method that takes an array of integers and a target integer.

It should return an array with the 2  indexes of the 2 items in the array that together sum the target value.

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < nums.Length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < nums.Length; y++)
        {
            if (nums[x] + nums[y] == target) { return new int[] { x, y }; }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Input: nums = [3,2,4], target = 6
Output: [1,2]
```

My question:

I get an error because not all paths return something. Which is understandable. But what should the method return if it can't find the 2 items?

Comment: a null? an empty array? throw an exception? (not recommended.) It is up to you

Comment: You should ask the person who assigned this task to you.

Comment: "what should the method return if it can't find the 2 items?" this is a question only you can answer. But if we take a look at existing examples of methods that look for indices like the [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-indexof(-0)) method, we can see that it returns a `-1` if the item cannot be found, but if your instructor left this part unspecified, then this is a great oppotunity to make up something fun ;) use your imagination

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: return `null`.

Oftentimes viewed as dangerous, outdated, "billion-dollar mistake", you name it. But an option nevertheless. Forces the client to perform `null`-checks, though. More convenient when `null` actually carries a semantic meaning.

Option 2: empty Array.

"Better" than `null` but in this case, you'd need to check if it has the desired length, so equally inconvenient for the scenario at hand.

Option 3: `bool TryTwoSum( int[] nums, int target, out int[] result )`

A common pattern when you do not want to throw exceptions. The result is only considered valid if the function returns `true`. You'll see it in a lot of `TryParse` signatures.
But this won't help if you must stick with your API.

Option 4: Throw an exception.

Not recommended to control flow. Since not finding a result would not really be an exceptional result, it shouldn't be handled as one. Also, exceptions are considered to be relatively expensive and can be clunky to handle. Among other drawbacks.

An opposing example would be to throw `ArgumentNullException` if `nums` is passed as `null`. That's clearly an *exceptional condition* that is indicative of a programming error at the client (= caller).

Option 5: return `new int[]{-1,-1}`

To indicate "no result" without exceptions, without `null` and with the expected amount of items. A little bit like returning `-1` from `IndexOf` as mentioned in comments by Mong Zhu. Drawback: would really need to be documented because it's not really *that* obvious that this is how "not found" is represented.

Option 6: A result - object

Basically a wrapper which contains an indicator if the operation has been successful and the result value. This could be implemented in various ways. Either with properties or with polymorphism ...
You may have seen this in Web-Controllers for example. May be a little overpowered for this scenario. But *can* lead to very readable code.

---

**Just to name a few.** Which one is correct? That's up to you and your requirements. Some may be more convenient than others for this specific case. There is not one option, that is *always* the best one.

Comment: Thanks. Just a question. Can I return null if i specified that the method should return int[ ] ?

Comment: Specified where? It would be at least surprising to a client if that specification did not include _"returns `null` if no such two indexes were found"_. _But_ that would be an "easy to guess" behavior.

Comment: If there is a specification that _you_ wrote: maybe share it (by [edit]ing the question) and we can give advice on what to do. If you didn't make any mention of the "no result" case up to now, maybe there is a way to both update the spec _and_ include the application of that spec in the code. In the end you need to make it work. And it cannot work if that means to break the specs ...

Comment: @Denis: Integers are value types (and as such, not nullable).  Arrays, however, are always reference types and are nullable.  Returning `null` is perfectly fine (if it makes sense in your situation)

Comment: @Flydog57 thank you, i'm just starting c# and it's new to me. It is like you said . Any tips for me from where or whom I should learn c#?

Comment: Don't learn a language. Learn how to code (no, actually: how to create software). The language is your tool. The framework is your shop. But you need to know the trade.

Comment: ok but i need to start somewhere .

Comment: Of course. I am just saying: There is more to it than just "learning a language". Learning a language is best done by speaking it, hearing it, reading it, writing it. Just pick a fun project and bite your teeth out. Yes, you cannot ask SO any odd question but the MS Docs are not too bad (any more) if you stick to the english ones. But they are more to lookup specifics, not to learn. But there is https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/csharp for starters ... and millions of tutorials on youtube... books I would only recommend some timeless ones. All the rest is too short-lived.

Comment: Maybe pick one up about Algorithms in general and a "Encyclopedia Algorithmica". It's no mistake to know what's talked about if someone says "yeah, but that's O(n²)" ...